# GTk printing 0ne p[age documents

Tags: gtk3

I have a problem printing one page documents in GTK 3.0.
Documents with more than one page are correctly printed but one page documents are not printed.
Because using the debugger in GNAT Studio 23.0w (20220512)  is sometimes a problem I have printed some inbetween results during running to the GTK textview. I found that the program not even reaches Draw_Page from Connect_and_Run.
My question is what should I do to also correctly print one page documents.
The insert_at_buffer function (procedure) is used to print to the Text view and result of these statements are seen below
For your information On_Print the code is using:

```
        Set_N_Pages (Print_Op, nr_Pages);
        Set_Use_Full_Page(Print_Op, true);
        Set_Unit (Print_Op, points);
        --DEBUG-------------------------------------------------------------------
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Set_Unit (Print_Op, points)"), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("nr_Pages       =") & Gint'image(nr_Pages) & " Filetype " & Windows'image(nb), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Ofirst_line    =") & integer'image(first_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("last_line      =") & integer'image(last_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("delta_lines    =") & integer'image(delta_lines), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Number         =") & long_float'image(Number), 0, true));
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Print_Op.Set_Print_Settings(Print_Set);
-------------------------------------------------------------------
--   procedure On_Draw_Page
--      (Self  : not null access Gtk_Print_Operation_Record;
--       Call  : Cb_Gtk_Print_Operation_Gtk_Print_Context_Gint_Void;
--       After : Boolean := False);
--------------------------------------------------------------------
        --DEBUG-------------------------------------------------------------------
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Print_Op.Set_Print_Settings(Print_Set)"), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("nr_Pages       =") & Gint'image(nr_Pages) & " Filetype " & Windows'image(nb), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Ofirst_line    =") & integer'image(first_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("last_line      =") & integer'image(last_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("delta_lines    =") & integer'image(delta_lines), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Number         =") & long_float'image(Number), 0, true));
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        On_Draw_Page(Print_Op, Draw);
        --DEBUG-------------------------------------------------------------------
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("On_Draw_Page(Print_Op, Draw)"), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("nr_Pages       =") & Gint'image(nr_Pages) & " Filetype " & Windows'image(nb), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Ofirst_line    =") & integer'image(first_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("last_line      =") & integer'image(last_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("delta_lines    =") & integer'image(delta_lines), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Number         =") & long_float'image(Number), 0, true));
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Result := Connect_and_Run(Print_Op ,Action_Print_Dialog, Main_Window);
--        --DEBUG-------------------------------------------------------------------
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Connect_and_Run(Print_Op ,Action_Print_Dialog, Main_Window)"), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("nr_Pages       =") & Gint'image(nr_Pages) & " Filetype " & Windows'image(nb), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Ofirst_line    =") & integer'image(first_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("last_line      =") & integer'image(last_line), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("delta_lines    =") & integer'image(delta_lines), 0, true));
        Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(nb), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Number         =") & long_float'image(Number), 0, true));
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In Draw_Page also someinformation lines are presented:

```
  nr := first_line;
  Cr := Get_Cairo_Context (Context);
  Set_Source_Rgb (Cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  Select_font_face(Cr, "Consolas", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
  Set_Font_Size(Cr, GDouble(10));
  if nr = 1 then
     pagenr := 1;
  else
     pagenr := pagenr + 1;
  end if;
  if pagenr rem 2 = 1 then
     width := 70;
  else
     width := 40;
  end if;
  if last_page_line > last_line then
     last_page_line := last_line;
  end if;
  len := 3;
  nr1 := 10;
  while last_line > nr1 - 1 loop
     nr1 := nr1 * 10;
     len := len + 1;
  end loop;
 --DEBUG-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(Window_Type), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("Draw_Page "), 0, true));
 Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(Window_Type), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("pagenr         = ") & integer'image(pagenr), 0, true));
 Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(Window_Type), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("first_line     = " & integer'image(first_line) & " Buffer = " & Windows'image(Window_Type)), 0, true));
 Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(Window_Type), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("last_line      = ") & integer'image(last_line), 0, true));
 Insert_At_Cursor(Text_Buffers(Window_Type), buf_string(To_Unbounded_String("last_page_line = ") & integer'image(last_page_line), 0, true));
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------

>With a one page document I got:
>Set_Unit (Print_Op, points)
>nr_Pages       = 1 Filetype GL
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 15
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 1.00000000000000E+00
>Print_Op.Set_Print_Settings(Print_Set)
>nr_Pages       = 1 Filetype GL
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 15
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 1.00000000000000E+00
>On_Draw_Page(Print_Op, Draw)
>nr_Pages       = 1 Filetype GL
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 15
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 1.00000000000000E+00
>Connect_and_Run(Print_Op ,Action_Print_Dialog, Main_Window)
>nr_Pages       = 1 Filetype GL
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 15
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 1.00000000000000E+00

>With a Multipage document I got:
>Set_Unit (Print_Op, points)
>nr_Pages       = 2 Filetype BI
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 68
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 2.00000000000000E+00
>Print_Op.Set_Print_Settings(Print_Set)
>nr_Pages       = 2 Filetype BI
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 68
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 2.00000000000000E+00
>On_Draw_Page(Print_Op, Draw)
>nr_Pages       = 2 Filetype BI
>first_line     = 1
>last_line      = 68
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 2.00000000000000E+00
>Draw_Page
>pagenr         =  1
>first_line     =  1 Buffer = BI
>last_line      =  68
>last_page_line =  57
>Draw_Page
>pagenr         =  2
>first_line     =  58 Buffer = BI
>last_line      =  68
>last_page_line =  68
>Connect_and_Run(Print_Op ,Action_Print_Dialog, Main_Window)
>nr_Pages       = 2 Filetype BI
>first_line     = 69
>last_line      = 68
>delta_lines    = 56
>Number         = 2.00000000000000E+00
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem.It was a problem caused by the arrangement of variuos statements creating Print_Op and Print_Set. I just tried variuos arrangements and all of a sudden the program worked